# Правильно ли используется указание автора?

Tags: html, html5

Правильно ли используется указание автора? Необходимо указать два человека в авторах.

```
<meta name="author" content="name1" name="author" content="name2">
```

Comment: Скорее всего, вторая пара `name` и `content` перепишет первую. Думаю, нужно два тега `meta`

Comment: С чего вы взяли что можно использовать множественное число, т.е. указывать несколько авторов на странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текущая [спецификация](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#meta-author) указывает (выделение и перевод мои)

> The value must be a free-form string giving the name of **one of the page's authors**.

> Значение должно быть строкой с именем **одного из авторов страницы**.

что косвенно подтверждает, что если авторов больше одного, то нужно просто добавить ещё один тег.

```html
<meta name="author" content="Илья Ильф">
<meta name="author" content="Евгений Петров">
```

Answer (score 1):

Стандарта вроде как нет.

```
<meta name="author" content="name1, name2">
```

Или пара тегов:

```
<meta name="author" content="name1">
<meta name="author" content="name2">
```

Дублирующиеся атрибуты в одном теге - точно плохо.

Comment: Я думаю при объявлении пары 2-е значение просто заменит первое и вообще где это видано чтобы на странице было 2 автора? Хотя то, что вы написали в одну строку, вполне себе годный вариант в таком случае.

Comment: Соавторство, мало ли)

Comment: Я думаю это не касается конструкции веб страницы, по крайней мере пока )